# how to pass argument in powershell function

Tags: powershell, parameters

Why does this code not work, how do you have to pass the parameters? what am I doing wrong:

```
cls

function __main{
   param(
         $apiEndpoint = $pathApi   
    )

   write-host $apiEndpoint

}

__main -pathApi"/ad/user/id"
```

output:

```
.
```

output-expected:

```
/ad/user/id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating functions in Powershell and using the param code, the params will define what parameters you can use.

In your code, you have the following:

```
   param(
            $apiHost = '........',
            $apiEndpoint = $pathApi,
            $requestMethod = 'GET'
    )
```

This means, your function `__Main` now has 3 parameters, `-ApiHost`, `-ApiEndpoint` and `-requestMethod`.

You have not specified `$pathApi`, so your function does not get the parameter passed to it, and thus it is empty.

If you however change your request to the following:

```
__main -apiEndpoint "/ad/user/id"
```

It will start working as expected.

Alternatively, change the param function as follows:

```
   param(
            $apiHost = '........',
            $pathApi = '',
            $requestMethod = 'GET'
    )

    $apiEndpoint = $pathApi
```

Keep in mind, that when working with restapi's, you usually want to add a / to the end of the path. If you don't, POST may not work.